# Object exists in Props but wont create element React Native Flow Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flowtype

I been trying to figure out why I am getting a flow error in my React Native project. I was unable to find a straight forward answer and thus I am confused. The project works but I still have this errors.

> Cannot create `TextInput` element because property `touched` is
>   missing in object type [1] but exists in props [2]. [1] [2]
>
> Cannot create `TextInput` element because property `valid` is missing
>   in object type [1] but exists in props [2]. [1] [2]

This is pointing at line 8 in the code which is below.

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

type Props = { style: Object, valid?: bool, touched?: bool };

const defaultInput = (props: Props) => (
    <TextInput   <--- Error Points Here!!!
      underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
      {...props}
      style={[styles.input, props.style, !props.valid && props.touched ? styles.invalid : null]}

    />
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    input: {
      width: "100%",
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: "#eee",
      padding: 5,
      marginTop: 8,
      marginBottom: 8
    },
    invalid: {
      backgroundColor: '#f9c0c0',
      borderColor: 'red'
    }
  });

export default defaultInput;
```

I am confused in why flow is throwing this error and what it means. I been trying to fix the problem but so far no solutions.

Any help would be appreciated. And I hope this helps others as well.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect it is because you have declared that `valid` and `touched` are optional.

Comment: That isn't the problem. When it wasn't optional the error still comes up. I got other errors when it wasn't an optional. I made it optional because some of my classes use it without being touched and validation.

Comment: Well what is the declared type of the props of `TextInput`?

Comment: TextInput is from the React Native framework. I'm am not sure about the props as I use a type Props to hold the props in.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to help here, but I also ran into this and started searching for an answer, so hoping this can help someone else.

I was able to fix the issue by consuming the props I was using in my functional component, like so:

```
type Props = {
   loading: boolean
};

export default function LoadingIndicator(props: Props) {

   // this is the key! Take out the props you've defined in your type above
   const { loading, ...other } = props;

   if (loading) {

      return (
         <View
            {...other}
            style={styles.loadingIndicator}>
            <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />
         </View>
      );
   } else return null;
}
```

Make sure to change out `...props` to whatever you named the leftover props, in this case `...other`.

That's it! The error will go away.